# Gradient and window re sizing with css

Tags: css

The situation:

A table with width set to `100%`, that has a cell inside with `1000px` width. The table is centered, and so is the cell.

I would like to have a gradient from left to right, and right to left that would end at the beginning of the centered cell, with the same color as the cell.

The problem is, to occupy the whole page, no matter what size the browser is, the table is set to `100%`, the cell is set to `1000px` so it'll never change its size,

**How can i achieve, if possible, what i want, making sure that in smaller resolutions/monitors or with window re sizing, the gradient will stop at the beginning of that cell, since gradients are set with percentage?**

Comment: What is the purpose of the table? Presumably you have other cells with data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, is it anything like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuZVT/ ?  If a gradient goes from left to right, then it naturally goes from right to left as well, or are you wanting to overlay gradients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you want?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="center">Your content goes here</td>
    <td class="right">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

styled such that

```
table {
  /* the table takes up all the space */
  width: 100%;
}
td.center {
  /* there is one container column */
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black; /* some fixed background color */
}
/* and two columns on the side which fade to some other color, in the respective directions */
td.left {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left, right, from(white), to(black));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(left, white, black);
  background:         linear-gradient(left, white, black);
}
td.right {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right, left, from(white), to(black));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, white, black);
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(right, white, black);
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(right, white, black);
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(right, white, black);
  background:         linear-gradient(right, white, black);
}
```

You can try this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qvum4/1/

**UPDATE**

However, if you don't have a specific reason to use tables, and you only want to achieve this effect, you shouldn't use tables.
There are a few jQuery gradient plugins around, that you can try to use.

Of you could develop a custom jQuery solution, in order to keep all the styling gibberish outside of the markup.
Try this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YnUpY/1/

Comment: I will update my reply when I get some feedback, since I'm not sure what the OP is asking.

Comment: Great! Without specifying a width to left and right, i didn't think it was possible to achieve this. I don't understand how the browser know that td.left and td.right are to fill the rest of the table. But it works perfectly, great job, thanks!

Comment: @guisasso: It's how tables work ;). Unless table columns are explicitly given a width or restricted in some way, then they will evenly occupy the remaining horizontal space (table columns always fill the width of the table). However, this does mean that the browser must download the table (and its contents) in its entirety before it can determine the column widths. However, it looks like you are using a table for layout, is there not a more semantic/accessible alternative?

Comment: It is for layout, but not for content, is that still a problem?

Comment: I wondered why you were specifically asking for a table. You can usually achieve horizontal aligning with divs and CSS, usually with float and margins.

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ . CSS3 gradients don't allow a fixed size block in the middle (as you do) while resizing the rest, but you might overcome this by detecting size change and recreating standard declarations accordingly.